# rewrite URl from www.m.example.com to m.example.com

Tags: url-rewriting, rule

I am trying to do a redirect in ASP.NET `web.config` which contains like `www.m.example.com` to `m.example.com`; I have tried different approaches but wasn't able to do it.

Comment: Please add some code on what do you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `web.config`, you could apply the following to your page:

```
<script runat="server">

private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    Response.AddHeader("Location","http://www.new-location.com");
}

</script>
```

[Read more here](http://knowledge.freshpromo.ca/seo-tools/301-redirect.php)

If you do still want to use the `web.config` file, you can do the following:

1. Open web.config in the directory where the old pages reside
2. Then add code for the old location path and new destination as follows:

   ```
   <configuration>
     <location path="services.htm">
       <system.webServer>
         <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://domain.com/services" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
       </system.webServer>
     </location>
     <location path="products.htm">
       <system.webServer>
         <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://domain.com/products" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
       </system.webServer>
     </location>
   </configuration>
   ```